Is it possible to get such a layout using grid?

Are there ways to use grid in my case?

Here what I tried: https://codepen.io/Nnekkka/pen/abrLJNq

Please add what you try inside your question, not in an external link (reason : Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?)

You can adjust the margin for the 5th, 11th and 12th items.


.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 32px;
  max-width: 800px;
  500px
}

.item {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}

.item:nth-child(6) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item:nth-child(11) {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.item:nth-child(12) {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.item:nth-child(13) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>



